# Obtain custom claims from CosmosDB in B2C policy

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-ad-b2c

We need to have a custom B2C policy to obtain custom claims from cosmosDB. Can someone suggest some pointers to get started on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a combination of the `Identity Experience Framework` (Custom Policies) and a "RESTful technical profile" (ie. Azure Function) to connect to, and return the claims that you have stored within CosmosDB.

Documentation for the [Identity Experience Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-trust-frameworks) and the [REST Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) should get you started.

Or, I recommend reviewing the following sample:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/rest-api-idp

Final note: I know that `User Flows` have a concept called `API Connectors` in preview mode that might help you avoid migrating to custom policies.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview